# What is web.xml file and what are all things can I do with it?

Tags: web-applications, web.xml

The [web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html) in Oracle's BEA WebLogic Server 8.1 Documentation pretty much sums up each element in a web.xml file. But I am also curious about points below:

1. Is there any configuration parameter which should be avoided like plague?
2. Any parameters related to performance or memory usage?
3. Security related risk due to common mis-configuration?

What else should I know about web.xml apart from element names and their usage?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

> What is web.xml file and what all things can I do with it ?

The `/WEB-INF/web.xml` file is the Web Application Deployment Descriptor of your application. This file is an XML document that defines everything about your application that a server needs to know (except the context path, which is assigned by the *Application Deployer and Administrator* when the application is deployed): servlets and other components like filters or listeners, initialization parameters, container-managed security constraints, resources, welcome pages, etc.

Note that reference you mentioned is pretty old (Java EE 1.4), there have been [few changes](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/100-new-features-in-servlets-25-2.html) in Java EE 5 and even more in Java EE 6 (which makes the `web.xml` "optional" and introduces [Web Fragments](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaEE/JavaEE6Overview_Part2.html#webfrags)).

> Is there any configuration parameter which should be avoided like plague?

No.

> Any parameters related to performance or memory usage?

No, such things are not configured at the application level but at the container level.

> Security related risk due to common mis-configuration ?

Well, if you want to use container-managed security constraints and fail at configuring them properly, resources won't obviously be properly protected. Apart from that, the biggest security risks come from the code you'll deploy IMO.

Answer (score 30):

> What all should I know about web.xml
>   apart from element name and their
>   usage ?

The SINGLE most important JSP configuration parameter of ALL TIME is in your web.xml.  Ladies and gentlemen, I give you... the **TRIM-DIRECTIVE-WHITESPACES** option!

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

This removes all the hundreds or thousands of lines of white space that you'll get in your generated HTML if you use any tag libraries (loops are particularly ugly & wasteful).

The other big one is the default web page (the page you get automatically sent to when you don't enter a web page in the URL):

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 8):

1. No, there isn't anything that should be avoided
2. The parameters related to performance are not in `web.xml` they are in the servlet container configuration files (`server.xml` on tomcat)
3. No. But the default servlet (mapped in a web.xml at a common location in your servlet container) should preferably disable file listings (so that users don't see the contents of your web folders):

   listings
           true

Answer (score 7):

I am trying to figure out exactly how this works too.  This site might be helpful to you.  It has all of the possible tags for web.xml along with examples and descriptions of each tag.

http://wiki.metawerx.net/wiki/Web.xml

Comment: Be a little careful though because I found one place where a dash was replaced with an underscore.  (that took a long time to debug).

Comment: why not add the comment to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

If using Struts, we disable direct access to the JSP files by using this tag in web.xml

```
 <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
  <web-resource-name>no_access</web-resource-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Deployment descriptor file** "web.xml" : Through the proper use of the
deployment descriptor file, web.xml, you can control many aspects of
the Web application behavior, from preloading servlets, to restricting
resource access, to controlling session time-outs.

**web.xml** : is used to control many facets of a Web application.
Using web.xml, you can assign custom URLs for invoking servlets, specify initialization
parameters for the entire application as well as for specific servlets, control
session timeouts, declare filters, declare security roles, restrict access to Web
resources based on declared security roles, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>pdfServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>pdfServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sapta.smartcam.servlet.pdfServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pdfServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pdfServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```