# Configuring Grizzly with a web.xml

Tags: jersey, web.xml, grizzly

I can start grizzly and deploy Jersey webservices on it with the following lines.

```java
protected HttpServer create() throws Throwable {
  ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.resource", "com.provider");
  HttpServer server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(uri, rc);
  return server;
}
```

But is there a way to load a `web.xml` instead of a `ResourceConfig`?

```xml
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.resource, com.provider</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Nope :-( It seems like Grizzly cannot handle web.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply yves. In the end I managed to [solve my issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608162/basic-http-authentication-with-jersey-grizzly) without it.

Comment: I've been struggling with this issue also, and could'nt run grizzly with web.xml also. Need to do your App config in your code!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is currently no direct way to configure grizzly with a `web.xml`. However I have used a partial solution that may be a beginning.

#### web.xml

First to understand the solution, we must understand what is the meaning of using a `web.xml`. It is basically use for configure your web application (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4538902/5147609) for a more detail). In this case we are configuring `init-params` for the servlet.

#### The (partial) solution

Instead of using the `web.xml` and instead of using `ResouceConfig.class`, we can use Grizzly as our servlet and initializing the parameters.
For example

```xml
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.resource, com.provider</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

would give something like :

```java
protected HttpServer create() throws Throwable {
    HashMap<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();

    //ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES is equal to "jersey.config.server.provider.packages"
    initParams.put(ServerProperties.PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "com.resource,com.provider");

    //Make sure to end the URI with a forward slash
    HttpServer server = GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/", initParams);
    return server;
}
```

With this, we can therefore put all the `init-params` that we want to.
However this solution cannot replace a whole `web.xml`.