# the maven does not automatically create a web.xml file in my java project by eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am newbie with Java and here is my problem.

I created a Demo Spring MVC by Eclipse and I saw that my project did not have this file :

```
Src -> main -> webapp -> WEB-INF -> web.xml
```

I mean, it does not have the folder webapp -> WEB-INF -> web.xml, so I did not have the file web.xml, so I can not do anything with the file web.xml as the tutorial.

I searched on internet and found this link
https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-error-web-xml-missing

And, I installed javaee, but I did not find javaee.

And I found this link, on stackoverflow

[Missing web.xml file from my maven application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735753/missing-web-xml-file-from-my-maven-application)

So, must I create the file web.xml by hand ? Or any other way to eclipse create it automatically ?

Could you please give me some advice ? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What *does* it have? How did you create the project? What do you mean by "installed javaee"?

Comment: @nitind : thanks for your comment. I created my project by "New Maven Project" and follow the tutorial, and "installed javaee" I followed this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBhAzf9ac9A